# Conditional Content Linked to Cookie Value Only Shows on 2nd Page Load

Tags: urls, cookies, parameter

I have the following 2 functions in **functions.php**

```
// Function to set the plan cookie
function set_plan_cookie() {
    if (isset($_GET['plan'])) {
        $plan_value = sanitize_text_field($_GET['plan']);
        setcookie('plan', $plan_value, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'set_plan_cookie', 1); // Set a priority of 1

// Function to display styles and cookie information based on the cookie value
function display_pricing_styles() {
    $plan_cookie = isset($_COOKIE['plan']) ? sanitize_text_field($_COOKIE['plan']) : '';

    if ($plan_cookie === 'full') {
        echo '<style>.pricing-full { display: block !important; } .pricing-discount { display: none !important; }</style>';
        echo "<h2>Cookie: $plan_cookie</h2>";
    } elseif ($plan_cookie === 'discount') {
        echo '<style>.pricing-full { display: none !important; } .pricing-discount { display: block !important; }</style>';
        echo "<h2>Cookie: $plan_cookie</h2>";
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'display_pricing_styles');
```

`function set_plan_cookie()` sets cookie name plan with a value based on a URL parameter **?plan=**
`function display_pricing_styles()` echos conditional style based on URL parameter being equal to **full** or **discount**

The problem is that while the cookie value changes everytime you change the URL parameter. The style + html only get reflected after 2 page refreshes. Please let me know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are relying on the URL parameter to set cookies, why not prioritize it over the cookie for the first page load?

At your second code block, changing the line `$plan_cookie` to this might help.

```
$plan_cookie = isset($_GET['plan']) && !empty($_GET['plan']) ? $_GET['plan'] : (isset($_COOKIE['plan']) ? sanitize_text_field($_COOKIE['plan']) : '');
```

Comment: Niiice! This works, thank you!